# Kafka cannot resolve Zookeper's DNS name

Tags: docker, dns, apache-kafka, kubernetes, apache-zookeeper

I have a kafka 0.10.1.0 cluster (2 nodes) and zookeeper 3.4.6 (3 nodes)

The clusters are hosted on Kubernetes following [this tutorial](http://www.defuze.org/archives/351-running-a-zookeeper-and-kafka-cluster-with-kubernetes-on-aws.html).

Relevant entries from Kafka's `server.properties`:

```
listeners=PLAINTEXT://0.0.0.0:9092
advertised.listeners=PLAINTEXT://kafka.internal.<companyname>.com:9092
zookeeper.connect=zookeeper-1:2181,zookeeper-2:2181,zookeeper-3:2181
```

Upon server startup, each Kafka broker fails quickly with the following. To me, it looks like it cannot resolve the DNS name `zookeeper-1`. I also attempted removing the ports from `zookeeper.connect`, although my reading of [the relevant code](https://github.com/apache/zookeeper/blob/ec20c5434cc8a334b3fd25e27d26dccf4793c8f3/src/java/main/org/apache/zookeeper/client/ConnectStringParser.java#L39), I don't believe that will make a difference.

Naturally, I confirmed that `zookeeper-1` can be resolved from within the cluster. Other containers from within the cluster can resolve the name.

I also attempted with a series of other aliases, including the services' DNS name and Zookeeper's load balancer(s), all of which I independently confirmed working. In each case, Kafka alone reported `Name or service not known`.

```
[2016-11-22 19:55:45,506] INFO Initiating client connection, connectString=zookeeper-1:2181,zookeeper-2:2181,zookeeper-3:2181 sessionTimeout=6000 watcher=org.I0Itec.zkclient.ZkClient@7722c3c3 (org.apache.zookeeper.ZooKeeper)
[2016-11-22 19:56:05,571] INFO Terminate ZkClient event thread. (org.I0Itec.zkclient.ZkEventThread)
[2016-11-22 19:56:05,572] FATAL Fatal error during KafkaServer startup. Prepare to shutdown (kafka.server.KafkaServer)
org.I0Itec.zkclient.exception.ZkException: Unable to connect to zookeeper-1:2181,zookeeper-2:2181,zookeeper-3:2181
    at org.I0Itec.zkclient.ZkConnection.connect(ZkConnection.java:71)
    at org.I0Itec.zkclient.ZkClient.connect(ZkClient.java:1227)
    at org.I0Itec.zkclient.ZkClient.<init>(ZkClient.java:156)
    at org.I0Itec.zkclient.ZkClient.<init>(ZkClient.java:130)
    at kafka.utils.ZkUtils$.createZkClientAndConnection(ZkUtils.scala:76)
    at kafka.utils.ZkUtils$.apply(ZkUtils.scala:58)
    at kafka.server.KafkaServer.initZk(KafkaServer.scala:327)
    at kafka.server.KafkaServer.startup(KafkaServer.scala:200)
    at kafka.server.KafkaServerStartable.startup(KafkaServerStartable.scala:39)
    at kafka.Kafka$.main(Kafka.scala:67)
    at kafka.Kafka.main(Kafka.scala)
Caused by: java.net.UnknownHostException: zookeeper-1: Name or service not known
    at java.net.Inet6AddressImpl.lookupAllHostAddr(Native Method)
    at java.net.InetAddress$2.lookupAllHostAddr(InetAddress.java:928)
    at java.net.InetAddress.getAddressesFromNameService(InetAddress.java:1323)
    at java.net.InetAddress.getAllByName0(InetAddress.java:1276)
    at java.net.InetAddress.getAllByName(InetAddress.java:1192)
    at java.net.InetAddress.getAllByName(InetAddress.java:1126)
    at org.apache.zookeeper.client.StaticHostProvider.<init>(StaticHostProvider.java:61)
    at org.apache.zookeeper.ZooKeeper.<init>(ZooKeeper.java:446)
    at org.apache.zookeeper.ZooKeeper.<init>(ZooKeeper.java:380)
    at org.I0Itec.zkclient.ZkConnection.connect(ZkConnection.java:69)
    ... 10 more
[2016-11-22 19:56:05,575] INFO shutting down (kafka.server.KafkaServer)
[2016-11-22 19:56:05,616] INFO shut down completed (kafka.server.KafkaServer)
```

Other info related to the Kafka image: It is based off [wurstmeister/kafka-docker](https://github.com/wurstmeister/kafka-docker) but updated to inherit from `openjdk:8-jre`.

Comment: have you tried using the Full Qualified Domain Name for these PetSets? 
Often times resolve methods don't work with the short name.

Comment: Can you ping `zookeeper-1` ? Can the hostname be resolved ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turns out that this was an issue with Kubernetes itself.

After an unrelated upgrade to v1.4.6 and no other changes, the names were able to resolve normally.